# Windows Phone 8.1 - get WebView Height

Tags: webview, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I want to add a WebView control to my page with its height to be has the HTML content's length.

The deafult behavior of the control is to stretch according to the availble space in the page, but not according to the actual HTML page's content, which in this case, results in a WebView with scrollbar and limited height.

I searched all over the web for answers but all I found was similar questions with no answers.

It seems to be very common problem and I find it hard to explain why no one ever encountered it.

I'll be glad for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a solution. :]

If you wish to do the same, feel welcome to check out my solution on GitHub:
https://github.com/romshiri/sizeable-webview

Comment: I used your control. But if I set userinteraction allowed to true for links to be clickable webview won't scroll. Did you handle it?

Comment: I', sorry but I'm not supporting this library anymore. Feel free to clone the code and change it. It isn't complicated at all. :)